# How to get left Sidebar to push main div rather than body

Tags: semantic-ui

I am attempting to create a page with a main menu bar across the top, with a single main container underneath.

I would like to add a left side bar that when it becomes active only pushes the main container and not the entire body which is the default behaviour.

I have attempted to change the sidebar.js to work on a named class rather than the body tag but without success.

Any pointers welcome.

I did notice, by live editing the semantic-ui website to use a right sidebar, that the right side bar does NOT push in the main menu.

Regards

Aidan